# Add a register value to new input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a button which add a new text field on a react form. I want this new input text field to store data on a register. How can I set this property?

Usually when you create a text field you use the `{...register("answer", { required: true })}`.

Currently I have a function called `addOption`:

```
const addOption = (e) => {
         if (nOptions < 6) {
             setNOptions(() => nOptions + 1);
             let ctn = document.getElementById("options");
             let newInpit = document.createElement("input");
             ctn.appendChild(newInput);
         }
     };
```

This function adds an input field and works well, but have no idea of how to add the the register property to this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the register property to the dynamically created input field, you can modify your addOption function to use React's JSX syntax instead of directly manipulating the DOM. You can create a new component for the input field and use useForm to manage the form state and registration.

EXAMPLE

```
const [nOptions, setNOptions] = useState(0);
      const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    
      const addOption = () => {
        if (nOptions < 6) {
          setNOptions(nOptions + 1);
        }
      };
    
      const onSubmit = (data) => {
        
        console.log(data);
      };
     
return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          {/* Existing input fields */}
          {[...Array(nOptions)].map((_, index) => (
            <input key={index} {...register(`answer${index}`, { required: true })} />
          ))}
          
          {/* Button to add new input field */}
          {nOptions < 6 && <button type="button" onClick={addOption}>Add Option</button>}
          
          {/* Submit button */}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
```